# System.AppDomainUnloadedException in test because of thread not stopping

Tags: .net, multithreading, f#, task-parallel-library, task

I have a server which starts a `TcpListener` in order to listen for incoming connections on a specified port. It is implemented as follows:

```
type TCPListenerServer(discoveryPort:int) =
    let server = new TcpListener (IPAddress.Loopback, discoveryPort)

    let activeConnections = new List<TcpClient>()
    let cancellationToken = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()

    let rec loop (pendingConnection:Task<TcpClient>) = async {            
        let newPendingConnection, client =
            match pendingConnection.Status with
            | TaskStatus.Created | TaskStatus.WaitingForActivation | TaskStatus.WaitingToRun 
            | TaskStatus.WaitingForChildrenToComplete | TaskStatus.Running  ->
                (None, None)
            | TaskStatus.Faulted ->
                let result = pendingConnection.Exception
                raise (new System.NotImplementedException())
            | TaskStatus.Canceled ->
                raise (new System.NotImplementedException())
            | TaskStatus.RanToCompletion ->
                let connectionTask = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync ()
                (Some connectionTask, Some pendingConnection.Result)
            | _ -> 
                raise (new System.NotImplementedException())

        // Add the new client to the list
        Option.iter (fun c -> activeConnections.Add c) client

        // Switch the new pending connection if there is one
        let connectionAttempt = defaultArg newPendingConnection pendingConnection

        // Check that the connections are still alive
        Seq.iter (fun (connection:TcpClient) -> if not connection.Connected then activeConnections.Remove connection |> ignore) activeConnections

        Async.Sleep 1000 |> Async.RunSynchronously
        return! loop connectionAttempt
    }

    member x.Start () =
        try
            server.Start ()
            let connectionTask = server.AcceptTcpClientAsync ()
            Async.Start (loop connectionTask, cancellationToken.Token)
        with ex ->
            server.Stop ()

    member x.Stop () =
        cancellationToken.Cancel ()
        server.Stop ()

    member x.ActiveConnections =
        activeConnections
```

And I am doing a very simple test that starts the server and makes sure no exception is thrown like follows:

```
let cleanupTest (serverUsed:TCPListenerServer) =
    serverUsed.Stop ()

[<TestMethod>]
[<TestCategory(Networking)>]
member x.``Start Server`` () =
    let server = new TCPListenerServer(44000)
    server.Start ()
    Async.Sleep 5000 |> Async.RunSynchronously

    cleanupTest server
```

The test passes, but I get the following error in my test output at the end of it:

> System.AppDomainUnloadedException: Attempted to access an unloaded
>   AppDomain. This can happen if the test(s) started a thread but did not
>   stop it. Make sure that all the threads started by the test(s) are
>   stopped before completion.

While looking back at my code, I have realised that my recursive loop never actually finishes, so I thought that could be the cause. My solution was to add the cancellation token (which is in my code I have pasted, it wasn't there initially) that I call `Cancel()` on when I stop the server.

Unfortunately, this has not solved the problem. What could be causing this exception (which is not failing my test) to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to wait until the cancellation was actually done. I did this by sleeping 2s after the call to `cancellationToken.Cancel ()` as I do not have access to the initial task created to do the following:

```
task.Wait ()
```